# Element type is invalid: Expected String

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

[image]

I checked all code but didn't found the mistake which can cause such a strange error. As you see it's exported while it says you likely forget to export.  Here is the code with the full list of imports:

```
 import "expo";
import React from "react";
import {Image, TouchableHighlight} from "react-native";
import {
  Content,
  Left,
  Right,
  Icon,
  CardItem,
  Card,
  Button,
  Text,
  Body,
  Row,
  Col,
  Grid,
  Thumbnail,
  ScrollView

} from "native-base";

import {dataRow1,dataRow2,dataRow3,dataRow4} from "../data/HomeData";
import { primary, secondary, grey } from '../styles/variables'; 


    const HomeContent = props => {
      return (
        <Content>
        <ScrollView horizontal>

          {dataRow1.map((item, idx) => {
            return <CardItemContainer {...props} key={idx} item={item} />;
          })}
            </ScrollView>
         <ScrollView horizontal>

          {dataRow2.map((item, idx) => {
            return <CardItemContainer {...props} key={idx} item={item} />;
          })}
            </ScrollView>
         <ScrollView horizontal>
              {dataRow3.map((item, idx) => {
            return <CardItemContainer {...props} key={idx} item={item} />;
          })}
            </ScrollView>
         <ScrollView horizontal>

          {dataRow4.map((item, idx) => {
            return <CardItemContainer {...props} key={idx} item={item} />;
          })}

        </ScrollView>
    </Content>
      );
    };


    const CardItemContainer = ({item, navigation}) => {
      return (
        <Card style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Items")}>
            <CardItem cardBody>
              <Image
                source={item.image}
                style={styles.img}
          />
            </CardItem>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <CardItem>
        <Text style={{color:grey}}> {item.title} </Text>

          </CardItem>
        </Card>
      );
    };


    const styles = {
      img:{
        height: 200,
         width: null,
          flex: 1
      },
    }

    export default HomeContent;
```

What can cause it and what is wrong? Can you help me please to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add all the import statements you have on your code

Comment: I've just added it :)

Comment: Can you try to change order of HomeContent and CardItemContainer please.

Comment: I've changed the order but it still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not imported any html tag reference from `react-native`. Every HTML tag is a element.

Let's suppose if you have `Text` tag then you must import it like `import { Text} from react-native .`

Answer (score 0):

You should import ScrollView from react-native instead of native-base.

After removing ScrollView from native base import's line include it in react-native's import line like this:

```
import {Image, TouchableHighlight, ScrollView} from "react-native";
```